# How to select ListBox items after appending through JQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I have got a ListBox in my view to which I am appending items using JQuery. I am able to append the items successfully but I cannot figure out how to select the required items which were appended.

My ListBox:

`@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.InternalEmailFileUploadIds, new MultiSelectList(new[] { "" }, Model.InternalEmailFileUploadIds), new { @class = "form-control select2-multiselect-checkbox", @placeholder = "File Upload Controls", multiple = "multiple", id = "internalEmailFileUpload" })`

Jquery to append items:

`$.each(response, function (i, item) {$('#internalEmailFileUpload').append('<option value="' + item.Id + '">' + item.Label + '</option>');})`

The `InternalFileUploadIds` variable in the model is populated but that doesn't seem to help.

My view consists of multiple tabs and I am not appending the items on page load. I am appending the items when the correct tab is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be quite a simple answer in the end.

Needed a *selected* in the required options that were added.

`$('#internalEmailFileUpload').append('<option value="' + item.Id + '" selected>' + item.Label + '</option>');`